How to Specify processId When Debugging with dlv-dap
According to the official documentation, I need to specify processId, when I want to attach to a remote running process.

When using attach mode outside of local host, you need to specify the processId in the config since the processId resolution feature cannot gather information about processes running remotely.

First, I checked the PID of the process (api-svr) that I need to debug on the remote server:
   PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                      
     1 root      20   0 1237620   6116   3024 S   0.0   0.0   3:24.63 supervisord                                                                                                                                  
    14 root      20   0 3110424 609456  21152 S   0.0   0.9  45:21.22 api-svr

Then, I forwarded a port locally using the command kubectl port-forward deployments/*** 11458:11458 -n *****, and entered dlv dap --listen=:11458 --log --log-output=dap in the remote pod. After starting the debug session locally, the following error occurred in the pod:
root:bin$ dlv dap --listen=:11458 --log --log-output=dap
DAP server listening at: [::]:11458
2024-05-29T18:26:56+08:00 warning layer=rpc Listening for remote connections (connections are not authenticated nor encrypted)
2024-05-29T18:26:56+08:00 debug layer=dap DAP server pid = 17968
2024-05-29T18:27:17+08:00 debug layer=dap DAP connection 1 started
2024-05-29T18:27:17+08:00 debug layer=dap [<- from client]{"seq":1,"type":"request","command":"initialize","arguments":{"clientID":"vscode","clientName":"Visual Studio Code","adapterID":"go","locale":"en","linesStartAt1":true,"columnsStartAt1":true,"pathFormat":"path","supportsVariableType":true,"supportsVariablePaging":true,"supportsRunInTerminalRequest":true,"supportsMemoryReferences":true,"supportsProgressReporting":true,"supportsInvalidatedEvent":true,"supportsMemoryEvent":true,"supportsArgsCanBeInterpretedByShell":true,"supportsStartDebuggingRequest":true}}
2024-05-29T18:27:17+08:00 debug layer=dap [-> to client]{"seq":0,"type":"response","request_seq":1,"success":true,"command":"initialize","body":{"supportsConfigurationDoneRequest":true,"supportsFunctionBreakpoints":true,"supportsConditionalBreakpoints":true,"supportsEvaluateForHovers":true,"supportsSetVariable":true,"supportsExceptionInfoRequest":true,"supportsDelayedStackTraceLoading":true,"supportsLogPoints":true,"supportsDisassembleRequest":true,"supportsClipboardContext":true,"supportsSteppingGranularity":true,"supportsInstructionBreakpoints":true}}
2024-05-29T18:27:17+08:00 debug layer=dap [<- from client]{"seq":2,"type":"request","command":"attach","arguments":{"name":"Attach to remote process","type":"go","debugAdapter":"dlv-dap","request":"attach","mode":"remote","program":"/usr/local/trpc/bin/api-svr","processId":14,"host":"127.0.0.1","port":11458,"__configurationTarget":6,"packagePathToGoModPathMap":{"/data/workspace/repos/protocol/csproto/api/tmp-1716954334266622446":"/data/workspace/repos/protocol/csproto/api/tmp-1716954334266622446","/data/workspace/repos/protocol/service/game-service/tmp-1716954459120449930":"/data/workspace/repos/protocol/service/game-service/tmp-1716954459120449930","/data/workspace/repos/protocol/service/game-service/tmp-1716954556533632740":"/data/workspace/repos/protocol/service/game-service/tmp-1716954556533632740"},"showRegisters":false,"showGlobalVariables":false,"substitutePath":[],"showLog":false,"logOutput":"debugger","dlvFlags":[],"hideSystemGoroutines":false,"dlvToolPath":"/data/workspace/go-env/bin/dlv","env":{"GOPATH":"/data/workspace/go-env/"},"__sessionId":"f2b8819c-65f7-4128-a239-ee57c9b57e9a"}}
2024-05-29T18:27:17+08:00 debug layer=dap parsed launch config: {
        "mode": "remote",
        "processId": 14,
        "backend": "default",
        "stackTraceDepth": 50
}
2024-05-29T18:27:17+08:00 debug layer=dap Failed to attach: no debugger found
2024-05-29T18:27:17+08:00 debug layer=dap [-> to client]{"seq":0,"type":"response","request_seq":2,"success":false,"command":"attach","message":"Failed to attach","body":{"error":{"id":3001,"format":"Failed to attach: no debugger found","showUser":true}}}
2024-05-29T18:27:17+08:00 debug layer=dap [<- from client]{"seq":3,"type":"request","command":"disconnect","arguments":{}}
2024-05-29T18:27:17+08:00 debug layer=dap [-> to client]{"seq":0,"type":"response","request_seq":3,"success":true,"command":"disconnect"}
2024-05-29T18:27:17+08:00 debug layer=dap [-> to client]{"seq":0,"type":"event","event":"terminated","body":{}}
2024-05-29T18:27:17+08:00 debug layer=dap DAP server stopping...
2024-05-29T18:27:17+08:00 debug layer=dap DAP server stopped

My VSCode launch.json configuration is as follows:
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Attach to remote process",
            "type": "go",
            "debugAdapter": "dlv-dap",
            "request": "attach",
            "mode": "remote",
            "program": "/usr/local/trpc/bin/api-svr",
            "processId": 14,
            "host": "127.0.0.1",
            "port": 11458,
        }
    ]
}

vscode error
